# App development for HP Slate (Slate, Windows tablet)

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I was wondering how the SDK is or if there is one for the HP Slate.

Would the apps be better off as a WPF app or a Silverlight app running off a browser on the Slate machines?

I understand that it's just a Windows 7 tablet, but I'm not sure if there are any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [Native Extensions for Silverlight](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl).

Answer (score 0):

check out here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704849(v=VS.85).aspx

i believe windows 7 has all the stuff built in for the stylus and such. As for wpf or silverlight, it all depends on what your goals are for the application. determine if it will be something that will be over the web or if it will be something done on its own LAN and go from there.

Comment: now that i think about it, isnt the HP Slate going to be based off of their WebOS instead of windows now? There are other tablets out there that use windows if that is what you are looking for. The ones we use at my company are from http://www.motioncomputing.com/ and i would highly recommend them. Real high quality stuff there. I've used the C5 and F5.